# Magento 2 - Custom input when Add To Cart

Tags: magento2, cart

Is it possible to add a custom step before the product is added to the cart?
What I want to do is:

- add a custom form to fill in extra information for the product
- the extra information will be associated with the product and being processed in the checkout process

Answer (score 2):

Well, (at least in the Luma and similar themes) there's already a `<form>` around the 'Add To Cart' button, so you in order to full fill the first part you could either simply override the `Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml` template used by the "product.info.addtocart" block or add your own block right before it like the following:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
    <block class="Company\Module\Block\Product\Extra"
        name="product.info.form.something.extra"
        template="Company_Module::extra.phtml"
        before="product.info.addtocart" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Then simply add your fields into this template.
Second part (processing) is a bit more tricky. The simplest path is probably by adding a couple of observers in your `events.xml` as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="company_module_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Company\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="company_module_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Company\Module\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Their exact implementations will depend on your exact needs.
An in-depth tutorial on the topic may be found at https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/